# Construct the critical region for the suitable test

Tags: statistics

**Question:** Let $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ be a sample from the distribution with probability density $p_{\theta}(x)=e^{-x+\theta} 1_{x \geq \theta}$. We want to test the null hypothesis $H_{0}: \theta \geq 0$ against $H_{1}: \theta<0$ at level $\alpha_{0}=0.1$. We choose $X_{(1)}$ as test statistic. Construct the critical region for the suitable (one-sided) test.

**My attempt:**
The function is similar to exponential distribution with $\lambda = 1$, so I tried working with the exponential distribution. The cumulative density function ($X_{1} \leq x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$. Now I can construct the critical region. I need to find $c$ such that: $\mathbb{P}(X_{1} \leq c | H_{0}) = 0.1$. So

$$
1 - e^{-c} = 0.1 \textrm{ with } \lambda = 1
$$
$$
e^{-c} = 0.9
$$
$$
c = -\log(0.9)
$$
So the critical region is $(-\infty, -\log(0.9)]$. However the answer should be $(-\infty, \frac{-\log(0.9)}{n}]$. Why do they divide by $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with $X_1$, but the statistic is really $X_{(1)}$ which is the minimum of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. You can check that $X_{(1)}$ is exponential with parameter $\lambda = n$.

---

Response to comment:

$$P(X_{(1)} > c) = P(X_1>c, X_2 > c, \ldots, X_n > c)
= \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i > c) = (e^{-c})^n.$$

Comment: Yes with $\lambda = n$ I get the same answer and I do understand the definition of $X_{(1)}$, however I don't understand why we take $\lambda = n$

Comment: Updated my answer @illegalsh